# Super class which uses the values from children

Tags: java, abstract-class

I wanted to implement a method in a abstract class that is called by the inherited classes and uses their values.

For instance:

```
abstract class MyClass{
    String value = "myClass";
    void foo(){System.out.println(this.value);}
}

public class childClass{
    String value="childClass";
    void foo(){super.foo();}
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new childClass.foo();
}
```

This will output "myClass" but what I really want is to output "childClass". This is so I can implement a "general" method in a class that when extended by other classes it will use the values from those classes.

I could pass the values as function arguments but I wanted to know if it would be possible to implement the "architecture" I've described.

A super method called by the inherited class which uses the values from the caller not itself, this without passing the values by arguments.

Comment: maybe you need to look for [Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) and one implementation in [C#](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternDecorator.aspx) (is a good sample that can be done in Java too).

Comment: Is there anyway to access the caller class? Like when an inherited class invokes super.foo is it possible to access the caller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
abstract class MyClass {

    protected String myValue() {
        return "MyClass";
    }

    final void foo() {
        System.out.println(myValue());
    }
}

public class ChildClass extends MyClass {
    @Override
    protected String myValue() {
        return "ChildClass";
    }
}
```

and so on

Answer (score 0):

This is a place where composition is better than inheritance

```
public class Doer{
   private Doee doee;

   public Doer(Doee doee){
       this.doee = doee;
   }
   public void foo(){
       System.out.println(doee.value);
   }
}

public abstract class Doee{
    public String value="myClass"
}

public ChildDoee extends Doee{
    public String= "childClass"
}
```

...

```
//Excerpt from factory
new Doer(new ChildDoee);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply want `value` in `MyClass` to be different for an instance of `childClass`.
To do this, change the value in the childClass constructor:

```
public class childClass {
    public childClass() {
        value = "childClass";
    }
}
```

#### Edited:

If you can't override/replace the constructor(s), add an instance block (which gets executed after the constructor, even an undeclared "default" constructor):

```
public class childClass {
    {
        value = "childClass";
    }
}
```

Comment: But `value` is a superclass field, it would be better practice to delegate its setting to the superclass constructor. The field itself should really be private.

Comment: Although I thought about this it seems I won't have another choice but to implement the difference between super and inherited classes through the constructor

Comment: @doubter See edited answer for an alternative (and actually better) way to code without changing/adding constructors

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik ...and yet it isn't a private field - because the super class has given visibility to it, this code is acceptable. I would think `protected` would be a better choice. `private` is the "classic" way, but convenience counts for something too

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking whether this is possible:

```
public class MyClass {
  void foo() {
    if (this instanceof childClass) // do stuff for childClass
    else if (this intanceof anotherChildClass) // do stuff for that one
  }
}
```

So the answer is "yes, it's doable", but very much advised against as it a) tries to reimplement polymorphism instead of using it and b) violates the separation between abstract and concrete classes.